# Split - apply - save csv for pandas using pure pandas / apply

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a boolean dataframe indexed by timestamps

```
df
>>>
timestamp     x0        x1        x2
2020-01-01    True      False     True
2020-01-02    True      False     True
2020-01-03    False     True      True
```

I want to save a csv of the column names for each row where the column is `True`, with the current timestamp as the csv filename. So in the example above, the desired output would be 3 csv's:

20200101.csv:

```
x0,
x2,
```

20200102.csv:

```
x0,
x2,
```

20200103.csv:

```
x1,
x2,
```

I have managed to do this using a for loop and some pandas methods, but it seems clunky. (This would be almost a one-liner in R, like using `split` and `lapply`.)

```
import numpy as np

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    tmp = row.replace({False: np.nan}).dropna()
    tmp = pd.DataFrame({"my_col": tmp.index.tolist()})
    file_name = ''.join(str(idx.date()).split('-'))
    tmp.to_csv(f"{file_name}.csv", index=False)
```

Is there a clean way to do this using pure pandas / map reduce / pandas apply and avoiding for loops?

Answer (score 1):

Had to stick with a loop to write out the CSVs.

```
df_out = df.melt(id_vars='timestamp').loc[lambda x: x['value']].sort_values('timestamp')

print(df_out)

    timestamp variable  value
0  2020-01-01       x0   True
6  2020-01-01       x2   True
1  2020-01-02       x0   True
7  2020-01-02       x2   True
5  2020-01-03       x1   True
8  2020-01-03       x2   True
```

Resorted to the much-maligned loop for output to CSV:

```
for t, frame in df_out.groupby('timestamp').variable:
    frame.to_csv(re.sub('-','',fr'd:\jchtempnew\SO\{t}.csv'), 
        index=None, header=None, line_terminator=',\r\n')

20200101.csv:
x0,
x2,

20200102.csv:
x0,
x2,

20200103.csv: 
x1,
x2,
```

Note that `line_terminator=',\r\n'` is included in `to_csv` to put a comma at the end of each line.

Comment: I think loops are *at least* okay to use for I/O, if not the preferred way. `melt` is a very good idea. Instead of the `unique()` approach, consider `for t, frame in df_out.groupby('timestamp').variable:` and proceed with `frame.to_csv(...)` as you did – I think that would make it pretty much a textbook answer.

Comment: @fsimonjetz I like it.  very clean.  I updated my answer to include.